# Problem with num trees in grid for ranger in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I have not found a way to specify the number of trees for 'ranger' method **in the grid** for caret:

```
data(iris)
control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 3,
  p = 0.8
)

tgrid <- expand.grid(
  .mtry = c(2,3),
  .splitrule = "gini",
  .min.node.size = c(2,3),
)


model <- train(
  Species ~.,
  data = iris,
  method = "ranger",
  trControl = control,
  tuneGrid = tgrid,
  num.trees=200,
  seed=42
)
```

I can only add it in 'train' function. The parameter is called num.trees', not 'ntree' (for Random Foerst) or 'n.trees' (for gbm).

By the way, I always MUST specify mtry, splitrule and min.node.size in the grid. It doesn't allow me to ignore any of these or add any other (like num.trees). Is there something I haven't taken into account? Where I can find the allowed grid parameters for each method (ranger, rf, gbm...)?

Thanks!